# SpringBatch reader+bean injections

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am trying to injecting repository in spring batch reader.But i am getting
"NullPonterException" in one case and It was injecting  in another way.

Please look into once,why it is happening like that.

**Case:1(Where injcetion is happening in the reader)**

```
public class ABCJobLauncher {

@Autowired
public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

@Autowired
private Reader reader;

public JobExecution startJobBatchProcessing(KeyRotationParameters keyRotationParameters) {

    JobExecution jobExecution = null;

    reader.setKeyRotationParameters(keyRotationParameters);


    try {

    Step step1 = stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").<BatchParameters, BatchParameters>chunk(1).reader(reader)
                .processor(processor).writer(writer).build();
    Job jobDetails = getJobdetails(keyRotationParameters.getTenantId(), step1);
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis())
                .toJobParameters();

        jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(jobDetails, jobParameters);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    return jobExecution;
}
}
```

and the corresponding "Reader" class is

```
 import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader;
 import org.springframework.batch.item.NonTransientResourceException;
 import org.springframework.batch.item.ParseException;
 import org.springframework.batch.item.UnexpectedInputException;
 import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
 import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Reader implements ItemReader<BatchParameters> {

@Autowired
private IRepository repopsitory;


private KeyParameters keyParameters;

public KeyParameters getKeyParameters() {
    return keyParameters;
}

public void setKeyParameters(KeyParameters keyParameters) {
    this.keyParameters = keyParameters;
}

@Override
public BatchParameters read()
        throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {


    VEntry vEntry = repopsitory.findById(id);

    **********(batchParameters)
            *********

    return batchParameters;

}

}
```

**CASE-2****(Where injection is not happenning in the reader)**

Suppose if i Create new instance for reader in instead of autowired in
"ABCJobLauncher".Then bean injection is not happening in the reader.

The corresponding code is

```
 @Component
public class ABCJobLauncher {

@Autowired
public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
private JobLauncher jobLauncher;



public JobExecution startJobBatchProcessing(KeyRotationParameters keyRotationParameters) {

    JobExecution jobExecution = null;

    Reader reader = new Reader();

    reader.setKeyRotationParameters(keyRotationParameters);
    Processor processor = new Processor();
    Writer writer = new Writer();

    try {



        Step step1 = stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").<BatchParameters, BatchParameters>chunk(1).reader(reader)
                .processor(processor).writer(writer).build();

        Job jobDetails = jobBuilderFactory.get(JobName).incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).flow(step1).end().build();
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis())
                .toJobParameters();

        jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(jobDetails, jobParameters);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    return jobExecution;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Suppose if i Create new instance for reader in instead of autowired in "ABCJobLauncher".Then bean injection is not happening in the reader.

Since you create the reader instance manually, you need to inject the dependencies manually. Because in this case, the reader is not managed by Spring, hence dependency injection will not be performed.

So in your "CASE-2", you need to do something like:

```
IRepository repository = ...; // create instance of IRepository
Reader reader = new Reader();
reader.setRepository(repository); // set the repository
reader.setKeyRotationParameters(keyRotationParameters);
```

Answer (score 0):

To complete @Mahmoud response you can inject the repository as you did in the first example and the set it to the reader:

```
@Autowired
private IRepository repopsitory;
@Component
public class ABCJobLauncher {

@Autowired
public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
private JobLauncher jobLauncher;  

public JobExecution startJobBatchProcessing(KeyRotationParameters keyRotationParameters) {

    JobExecution jobExecution = null;

    Reader reader = new Reader();
    reader.setRepository(repository); // set the repository
    reader.setKeyRotationParameters(keyRotationParameters);
    Processor processor = new Processor();
    Writer writer = new Writer();

    try {



        Step step1 = stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").<BatchParameters, BatchParameters>chunk(1).reader(reader)
                .processor(processor).writer(writer).build();

        Job jobDetails = jobBuilderFactory.get(JobName).incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).flow(step1).end().build();
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis())
                .toJobParameters();

        jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(jobDetails, jobParameters);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    return jobExecution;
}
```